# Pattern for using Meteor with advanced SVG or Canvas Ouput

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js, meteor

Is it sensible to use Meteor for a reactive data display that isn't primarily HTML based?

To be specific, I want to display a graph database as a set of boxes connected by lines. I'd like to allow live interaction with these boxes, and I'd also like them to be reactive, so if one user edits the data the display of any other users currently viewing the graph will update.

Meteor seems great for the reactivity, but most of the examples I've found focus on either HTML templates or very simple API interactions for doing things like adding a pin to a map.

I am currently thinking about using SVG or Canvas to display the graph database, but I am very unsure how best to integrate that with Meteor and/or some other library like maybe D3.

Comment: Blaze (the Meteor template rendering engine) comes with a native SVG support, and it works quite well from my experience.

Comment: Good question. One of the biggest difficulties with using SVG in Meteor right now is choosing between doing a fully reactive SVG versus using the well-established data join based functionality of D3, which is somewhat tricky to hook up to collections efficiently.

Comment: I just noticed there's a recent "Meteor Cookbook" entry on using D3 https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Reactive-D3-Visualizations-YUR9JT4mrm9

Answer (score 2):

I found that Meteor works perfectly with canvas, I don't know if what I do is the best practice but I got the best results using Kinetic.js (available for Meteor via "mrt install kineticjs" and I use the template engine to call on functions that set up the elements on my canvas, this is a small example of a code I use to place the players on my map:

the Template:

```
<template name="canvas_map">
<div id="grid_map" class="grid"></div>
{{#with clear_canvas}}
    {{#each human}}
        {{handle_member_pos}}
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

the "clear_canvas" helper sets up a new Kinetic.Stage and the "handle_member_pos" helper gets a human object and places it on said canvas.

here are the helpers (coffeescript):

```
     Template.canvas_map.clear_canvas = =>
        if Session.get('init')
            kinetic_elements.stage = new Kinetic.Stage
                container: 'grid_map'
                width: 385
                height: 375
            kinetic_elements.layer = new Kinetic.Layer()
        else
            false
 Template.canvas_map.handle_member_pos = ->
        [x, y] = pos_to_str @profile.pos
        left = Math.floor(11 * x)
        top = Math.floor(11 * y)
        name = @profile.name
        unless kinetic_elements.avatars[name]?
                imageObj = new Image()
                imageObj.onload = =>
                    element = new Kinetic.Image
                        x: left
                        y: top
                        image: imageObj
                        width: 50
                        height: 50
                    element.on 'click', (evt) =>
                        Session.set 'selected', @profile._id
                        window.propogation = false
                        false
                    kinetic_elements.layer.add element
                    kinetic_elements.avatars[name] = [element, text]
                    kinetic_elements.stage.add kinetic_elements.layer
                imageObj.src = 'human.png'
            else
                element = kinetic_elements.avatars[name]
                layer = kinetic_elements.layer
                element.setX left
                element.setY top
                layer.draw()
        return
```

as I said, I'm not sure if that is the best practice, but it works great for me, hope this helps in any way.

Comment: That example is very instructive about this question and actually opens my mind a bit about Meteor in general, so thanks a lot!

Comment: glad I could help, also, I highly recommend working with Kinetic.js, normally with canvas you lose touch with elements once you draw them in the canvas, Kinetic allows you to keep in touch with your elements forever.