# Getting data from <select> value and paste it in <canvas>

Tags: javascript, image, meteor, drop-down-menu, meteor-blaze

i'am new here so I hope that I'am asking the right question in the right place . First of all I searched in the website to find some solution for my problem , but I didn't succeed . So further more I decide to ask you to step in and help me . Literally i'am trying to paste some data/image from the dropdown menu to the canvas.

**main.html**

```
    <main>
        <canvas class='background' width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    ...
    ...
        {{>selectValue}}
      </main>

<template name='selectValue'>
  <td>
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option value='' disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
      <option data-img-src='img/person.png'>Option 1</option>
      <option data-img-src='img/progress.png'>Option 2</option>
      <option data-img-src='img/success.png'>Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</template>
```

and here is my attempt to get the value of every select , but it doesn't work.
**main.js**

```
Template.selectValue.events({
  "change #dropdown": function (event, template) {
    var selectValue = template.$("#dropdown", '.background').val();

    console.log(selectValue);

  }
});
```

on the bright side i'am getting in the console.log that one of the Options are choosen , but still I don't get any image displayed in the CANVAS . I think that i'am on the right track ...

Comment: check this - https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

Comment: @TiagoMartinho Nice , but I think this is not the solution that I'am looking for . The image must be selected from the dropdown menu .

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want

I followed the example I shared in the comment.

```js
let drop = document.getElementById('dropdown');
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let imageObj = new Image();

drop.addEventListener('change', function () {
  imageObj.src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.img;
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
  };
});
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value='' disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option data-img='https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg'>Option 1</option>
    <option data-img='https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed1.jpg'>Option 2</option>
    <option data-img='https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed3.jpg'>Option 3</option>
</select>
    
<canvas id="myCanvas" class='background' width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: That seems to be legit . But I receive an error that says ' main.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null ' . And If I have images from my local folder (project folder /img/person.png) can I insert them with 'data-img-src='' ' ?

Comment: In your example, the element canvas is missing the ID, maybe that's the error. Yes, do not give the name `-img-src`, because otherwise it will give error in javascript, due to hiffen.

Comment: ` {{>canvas}} {{>selectValue}}
  </main>
</body>
<template name='canvas'>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" class='background' width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</template>
<template name='selectValue'>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value='' disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option img-src='/img/person.png'>Option 1</option>
    <option img-src='/img/progress.png'>Option 2</option>
    <option img-src='/img/success.png'>Option 3</option>
  </select>
</template>`  
Now the error is gone but it doesn't display nothing.

Comment: Have you tried this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498795/pattern-for-using-meteor-with-advanced-svg-or-canvas-ouput

Answer (score 0):

**main.html**

```
 <main>
    {{>canvas}}
   ...
    {{>selectValue}}
  </main>

<template name='canvas'>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" class='background' width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</template>

<template name='selectValue'>

  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value='' disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    {{#each categories}}
    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>


</template>
```

**main.js**
And then in the JS you have to add also this

```
Template.selectValue.helpers({
  categories: function () {
    return ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
  }
});
```

I think this is on the right direction to get the data , but i am not sure how to display it in the canvas .